# while every value in array is different than specific int value

Tags: c++, arrays, loops

I have an array of values e.g. 1, 4, 7, 2.
I also have another array of values and I want to add its values to this first array, but only when they all are different from all values that are already in this array. How can I check it? I've tried many types of loops, but I always ended with an iteration problem. 
Could you please tell me how to solve this problem? I code in c++.

```
int array1[7] = {2,3,7,1,0};
int val1 = rand() % 10;
int val2 = rand() % 10;
int array2[2] = {val1, val2};
```

and I am trying to put every value from array2 into array1. I tried loop

```
for (int x:array2)
{
   while((val1 && val2) == x)
   {
      val1 = rand() % 10;
      val2 = rand() % 10; 
   }
}
```

and many more, but still cannot figure it out. I have this problem because **I may have various number of elements for array2**. So it makes this "&&" solution infinite.
It is just a sample to show it more clearly, my code has much more lines.

Comment: Do you actually _need_ an array, specifically? Could use use `std::set<int>` instead?

Comment: Please show the actual code you have tried that is not working for you.  Searching an array for a specific value is pretty trivial to do. Or you can use the standard [`std::find()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) algorithm to do the search for you

Comment: yes, it would be better to figure it out for array

Comment: What do you do when you have filled out the array?

Comment: `(val1 && val2) == x` doesn't do what you think it does, and a single condition won't even work here. You also don't track which array values have been assigned in `array1` so it's not even clear where we should put the new values.

Comment: `std::any_of` and `std::find` should work together to help you.  If "any of" `array2` (any element in `array2`) is found in `array1` then don't combine the arrays.

Comment: it was just an example, because for me number of val is might be even 3 or 4. I know I can't solve it with a single condition.

Comment: @Wyck , I think it might be helpful. I hope! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, you have a few problems here. If I understand the problem, here's what you want:

A. You have array1 already populated with several values but with space at the end.
1. How do you identify the number of entries in the array already versus the extras?

B. You have a second array you made from two random values. No problem.

You want to append the values from B to A.
2. If initial length of A plus initial length of B is greater than total space allocated for A, you have a new problem.

Now, other people will tell you to use the standard template library, but if you're having problems at this level, you should know how to do this yourself without the extra help from a confusing library. So this is one solution.

```
class MyArray {
public:
    int * data;
    int count;
    int allocated;

    MyArray() : data(nullptr), count(0), allocated(0) {}
    ~MyArray() { if (data != nullptr) free(data); }

    // Appends value to the list, making more space if necessary
    void add(int value) {
        if (count >= allocated) {
            // Not enough space, so make some.
            allocated += 10;
            data = (data == nullptr) malloc(allocated * sizeof(int))
                 : realloc)data, allocated * sizeof(int));
        }
        data[count++] = value;
    }

    // Adds value only if not already present.
    void addUnique(int value) {
        if (indexOf(value) < 0) {
            add(value);
        }
    }

    // Returns the index of the value, if found, else -1
    int indexOf(int value) {
        for (int index = 0; index < count; ++index) {
            if (data[index] == value) {
                return index;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }

}
```

This class provides you a dynamic array of integers. It's REALLY basic, but it teaches you the basics. It helps you understand about allocation / reallocating space using old-style C-style malloc/realloc/free. It's the sort of code I was writing back in the 80s.

Now, your main code:

```
MyArray array;
array.add(2);
array.add(3);
array.add(7);
// etc. Yes, you could write a better initializer, but this is easy to understand

MyArray newValues;
newValues.add(rand() % 10);
newValues.add(rand() % 10);

for (int index = 0; index < newValues.count; ++index) {
    array.addUnique(newValues.data[index]);
}
```

Done.

The key part of this is the addUnique function, which simply checks first whether the value you're adding already is in the array. If not, it appends the value to the array and keeps track of the new count.

Ultimately, when using integer arrays like this instead of the fancier classes available in C++, you HAVE TO keep track of the size of the array yourself. There is no magic .length method on int[]. You can use some magic value that indicates the end of the list, if you want. Or you can do what I did and keep two values, one that holds the current length and one that holds the amount of space you've allocated.

With programming, there are always multiple ways to do this.

Now, this is a lot of code. Using standard libraries, you can reduce all of this to about 4 or 5 lines of code. But you're not ready for that, and you need to understand what's going on under the hood. Don't use the fancy libraries until you can do it manually. That's my belief.